Nuxt 3 middleware redirect based on IP country code not working when deployed to Netlify
I'm trying to forward traffic to a specific slug based on the user's country code after an IP address lookup.
It works perfectly locally but it's not working when I deploy to Netlify.
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  const targetPathDe = '/de-de'
  const targetPathEn = '/de-en'

  // Prevent middleware from redirecting if already on the target path
  if (to.path === targetPathDe || to.path === targetPathEn) {
    return
  }

  const ipApiUrl = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=countryCode'

  try {
    // Use native fetch to get IP data
    const response = await fetch(ipApiUrl)
    const ipData = await response.json()

    // Check the country code from IP data
    if (ipData.countryCode === 'DE') {
      return navigateTo(targetPathDe)
    } else {
      return navigateTo(targetPathEn)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching IP data:', error)
    return navigateTo(targetPathEn)
  }
})

Locally, I'm running npm run dev and Netlify is npm run build.

What happens if you build your app locally in the same way? Btw, do you use SSR and not SSG? Netlify does not really support SSR (24/7 running NodeJS server). You can also download the Netlify CLI to mimic the behavior of production on your local machine.

Btw, Netlify also has some Edge functions with geolocation, if you want to do it on the edge: https://edge-functions-examples.netlify.app/

Thank you. I ended up using the Netlify geolocation edge function for now.

@kissu if he's running his site via npm run build and the site isn't exploding, then Netlify is likely using lambdas for SSR like Vercel.

@JoshDeltener can you run a fully SSR Nuxt app as in Heroku tho? Afaik Netlify is not providing a full 24/7 running Node server but I might be wrong because never used it for such a purpose. Still, I doubt it on a free plan.

This is using my free plan, yes it appears Netlify uses cloud functions for SSR.
PREVIEW: https://netlify-ssr-nuxt-test.netlify.app/ , REPO: https://github.com/hecktarzuli/netlify-ssr-test

@JoshDeltener hm, I thought more of generating pages on the fly etc, this is a very simplistic "SSR" app.

How is this "SSR", it's literally being rendered on a server :P

OP considered using the geolocation edge function for now.
It is easier to implement and probably more precise too!

From what I can see from ip-api.com, that uses the caller's IP address to detect country.  In which case, assuming you're running this server-side, that IP would always be the IP of the running server and not your client.  This would work locally as your IP is both the user and the server.

IP-based localization is quite funky anyway IMO. Feel like using Edge functions for that purpose is more accurate overall because your PC will not travel at the end of the world to serve you a website.

100%, if you can use Edge functions and/or available headers (like what AWS adds) I'd certainly do that!

Good point! The Edge function has been working great, and it's instant response, too. That in itself and being more reliable has been a better option.
